# SPQueryThrottledException during SPListItem.Update

Tags: document-library, 2016, insert-update-listitem

We have SharePoint 2016 On-Premise, document library with folders and documents. During folder update (`SPListItem.Update`) we receive **SPQueryThrottledException**.

We update only fields single line of text, people, hyperlink. The Document Library doesn't have lookups.

Document library has about 25000 unique permissions assigned to folders that is not a limit for On-Premise.

ULS:

> ListItemUpdate Failure:
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQueryThrottledException: The attempted
>   operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold
>   enforced by the administrator. --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The attempted operation
>   is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by
>   the administrator.      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.AddOrUpdateItem()
>
> **Inner exception**: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view
>   threshold enforced by the administrator., StackTrace:     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.AddOrUpdateItem(Boolean bAdd, Boolean
>   bSystem, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bNoVersion, Boolean
>   bMigration, Boolean bPublish, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin,
>   Guid newGuidOnAdd, Int32& ulID, Object& objAttachmentNames, Object&
>   objAttachmentContents, Boolean suppressAfterEvents, String filename,
>   Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.UpdateInternal(Boolean bSystem,
>   Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Guid newGuidOnAdd, Boolean bMigration,
>   Boolean bPublish, Boolean bNoVersion, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean
>   bCheckin, Boolean suppressAfterEvents, String filename, Boolean
>   bPreserveItemUIVersion)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.Update()

Microsoft tells that it can throw such exceptions https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee536748(v=office.15)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

BUT in which cases? How to fix this? Refelctor does not give an answer as well.